# AngularJS Broadcast not working on first controller load

Tags: events, angularjs, broadcast, publish-subscribe

In this PlunkerDemo, I'm trying to broadcast an event from the parent controller to child controller. However doing it directly in the parent controller won't work. The handler doesn't register the event. However doing it based on an ng-click or based on setTimeout, it works. Is it due to the scope life cycle?

http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/ZU0XNK?p=preview

See the comments of the accepted answer. They explain my problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any changes to angular scope must happen within the angular framework, If any changes have to be made outside the framework we have to use the [.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) function.

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework.

In your case you are triggering the [$broadcast](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) within `setTimeout`, where the callback gets called outside the angular framework.

So you have two solutions, either use the [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) service provided by angular or use [.$apply](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$apply) function.

I prefer to use the `$timeout` function.

```
var ParentCtrl = function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout){

    $scope.broadcast = function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('Sup', 'Here is a parameter');
    };

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.$broadcast('Sup');
    }, 1000);

    //this one does not work! Most likely due to scope life cycle
    $scope.$broadcast('Sup');

    $scope.$on('SupAgain', function(){
        console.log('SupAgain got handled!');
    });

};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/NBcoTk?p=preview)

Using `$apply`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.$broadcast('Sup');
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can you explain why this one doesn't work: $scope.$broadcast('Sup'); The one with the comments about //this one does not work! Most likely due to scope life cycle?

Comment: If you add two console stmts as given in [this demo](http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/hLJANQ?p=preview), you can find that when the event is fired the child controller is not yet executed hence the event handler is not registered

Comment: Oh I see. So I guess they need to be part of the timeout, in order to wait for all controllers to initialise?

Comment: Also, one question, why would you choose to do $timeout then $apply? Why not just straight $timeout? What are the advantages?

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake

Comment: This only seems to work with a significant timeout (>100 ms in my case). Isn't there a more "deterministic" solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A more reliable option can be to use $interval in child controller. So, instead of having significant timeout, there will be polling every small interval.
Also, instead of broadcast, use a service with a flag. Every poll will check if flag is set. When the flag is set by parent controller, the timer will be stopped during next poll. And that can indicate the event happened. The parent controller can also share data with child controller, via service.